# Transaction issue with knexjs, typescript and mariadb

Tags: typescript, mariadb, knex.js

I want to have a transaction, in typescript, to refresh some data in a table. To do so the following steps need to apply:

1. Truncate all the records from a table
2. Set the AUTO_INCREMENT to 1
3. Insert the new records in the table

If something goes wrong I would like to rollback the transaction and not alter the existing records in the db table.

I have tried different things but I think I am missing something and I wish someone can spot what I am doing wrong.

1st Attempt

```
await knex.transaction(async (trx) => {
  await knex(tableName).truncate().transacting(trx);
  await knex.raw(`ALTER TABLE ${tableName} AUTO_INCREMENT=1;`).transacting(trx);
  await knex(tableName).insert(data).transacting(trx);
  await trx.commit();
});
```

2nd Attempt

```
await knex.transaction(async (trx) => {
  try {
    await knex(table).truncate().transacting(trx);
    await knex.raw(`ALTER TABLE ${table} AUTO_INCREMENT=1;`).transacting(trx);
    await knex(table).insert(data).transacting(trx);
    await trx.commit();
  } catch (e) {
    await trx.rollback();
  }
});
```

3rd Attempt

```
const promisify = (fn: any) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => fn(resolve));
const trx: knex.Transaction  = <knex.Transaction> await promisify(this.knex.transaction);
try {
  await this.knex(this.table).truncate().transacting(trx);
  await this.knex.raw(`ALTER TABLE ${this.table} AUTO_INCREMENT=1;`).transacting(trx);
  await this.knex(this.table).insert(data).transacting(trx);
  await trx.commit();
  return Promise.resolve(data);
} catch (e) {
  await trx.rollback();
  return Promise.reject(e);
}
```

Any idea would be really useful.

Comment: Thanks for writing this; I'm having exactly the same issue. Both answers below help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With mysql all schema altering DDL queries does implicit commit and they cannot be rolled back. So you need to change your implementation to guarantee integrity of db in some other way.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it that way.  Instead:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
populate `new`
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

If the `CREATE` or `populate` fail, then abandon the task; no harm done.  (Well, need to `DROP TABLE real`.)

The `RENAME TABLE` is very fast, and atomic, and unlikely to fail.

This approach has the advantage that, to other queries, the `real` table is available and fully populated the entire time.

Comment: nice trick, what happens to foreign key references pointing to original table? I suppose one has to drop / recreate them in a way that they point to the new table instead?

Comment: @MikaelLepistö - Ah, yes, another reason why I avoid FKs.  Try disabling FKs during the operation.